# Conflicts between neocomplete and vim-multiple-cursors in Vim

Tags: vim

This isn't technically a programming question, but maybe someone here has discovered a workaround since Vim and the two plugins listed are pretty popular.

I have Vim 7.4 and there is an issue using https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors with https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim.

Have neocomplete enabled while trying to type input using multiple cursors results in a very long input lag (and missing characters as well). Using the neocomplete option to lock neocomplete so that the popup dialogue does not appear does not help. Disabling neocomplete does remove the input lag with multiple cursors. Has anyone found a workaround or are they using these two plugins together with no issues?

Some extra information, I'm running a Mac and Vim 7.4.52 and using Neobundle as my package manager.

Comment: I stopped using vim-multiple-cursors because of that lag. I find its implementation similar to running a macro inside a loop, which can inadvertently start a long-running operation you can't cancel. I ended up just learning the vim-native way of doing a lot of the same things.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of `vim-multiple-cursors` have solved the problem. It now provides two functions `Multiple_cursors_before/Multiple_cursors_after`, which will be executed before start and after quit `vim-multiple-cursors`. You can implement these two functions in `.vimrc`, add code like `NeoCompleteLock/NeocompleteUnlock`.

Click [here](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors#multiple_cursors_beforemultiple_cursors_after-default-nothing) to see the detail.